# Identity Server 4. Getting error when using self-signed certificate

Tags: ssl, identityserver4

I have an Identity Server, a Web API and a frontend app. Usually they're running on localhost and it works fine. Now I need to run the app on my local IP address. I changed all the settings from localhost:port to <my_ip>:port and I'm getting the following error in the Web API:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '<my_ip>:5003/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '<my_ip>:5003/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

I tried to generate a self signed certificate and add to the certificate store, I tried many solutions on SO i.e. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58136780/6188783). All I achieved is switching from this error and `Keyset does not exist`

This is how I try to load the certificate:

```
var key = Configuration["certBase64"]; // exported from store as x509 base64 encoded
                var pfxBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
                var cert = new X509Certificate2(pfxBytes, "<certificate-pwd>", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
                builder.AddSigningCredential(cert);
```

What am I missing?

---

UPDATE

I also tried to use a local DNS name for my IP. On my router I set up forwarding from myapp.local to <my_ip>. Then I created a self signed certificate with Subject and DNS name = myapp.local, but it didn't help.

The current error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'myapp.local:5003/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'myapp.local:5003/.well-known/openid-configuration'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use HTTPS and certificates when you try co connect to a service using an IP-address. You must always have a domain name and a valid certificate that your local machine trust.

Comment: I set up a DNS entry and the error still persist:  ```Unable to retrieve document from: 'app.local:5003/.well-known/openid-configuration'```. I did issue a self signed certificate with subject CN=app.local

Comment: you must add it to the local certificate store to make it trusted, do verify that you can first access the URL from your browser before you try it from code.

Comment: the url is accessible, the certificate is added to current user personal and trusted, as well as to local machine personal and trusted stores

Comment: what error do you get when you use a domain name instead? perhaps you can update your question?

Comment: the same error, but with the domain name instead of <my_ip>

Comment: are you running it in a container?

Comment: I would add a rule to your local hosts file that would map myapp.local -> to point to your local machine. can also be that your firewall is blocking you?

Comment: It didn't work. I turned off the firewall and added <my_ip> myapp.local to the hosts file, the error is the same

Comment: How do you add the HTTPS certificate to your application? builder.AddSigningCredential(cert); does not do that.

Comment: it was created on the first app run, I believe. At least I can see asp.net core development certificate in current user/personal and trusted stores

Comment: How how do you add the myapp.local cert to the ASP.NET Core application?

Comment: That worked! Thanks man, I completely forgot about a certificate for ASP.NET Core apps :)

Comment: Glad you made it!